# I don't understand how to make an adjustable variable

Tags: python

So I was reading a python programming book earlier and I can't understand how adjustable variables work.
Like lets say i have
c = 0
how would I write a program so that when a condition is met it would record that it was met by adding 1 to c?

Comment: `c = c + 1 if some_condition else c`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
c = 0
if conditione:
    c = c + 1
else:
    c = 2
```

Comment: ok but what if I want it to keep going up like say I was recording the number of times something happened in a year. how would that work?

Answer (score 1):

```
cond = int(input('Is condition met (1 - yes, 0 - no)? '))

c = 0
if cond:
    c += 1

print('c=', c)
```